# Gradient /Bevel effect to text in fabricjs canvas

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas, fabricjs

how can i give Gradient or bevel effect to text in fabricjs Text  ??

http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2/
here examples is given for shapes and all , i tied it with text but not working ??

```
    hw[i] = new fabric.Text($(this).val(), {
                left : 100,
                top : 100,
                fontSize : 20
            });
 hw[i].setGradient('fill', {
  x1: 0,
  y1: 0,
  x2: 0,
  y2: circle.height,
  colorStops: {
    0: "red",
    1: "blue"
  } });
```

Any suggestion

Answer (score 2):

you give here *circle.height* value for *y2*, try out with *hw[i].height* instead

in my own test i noticed the need to remove object width & height divide by two from all x & y properties,

```
var odx = obj.width  /2, ody = obj.height /2;

obj.setGradient('fill',{
    x1: gradient.start.x - odx,
    y1: gradient.start.y - ody,
    x2: gradient.end.x   - odx,
    y2: gradient.end.y   - ody,
    colorStops : colors
});
```

you can found a concrete gradient text exemple [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r043v/xmm4M/)